# How can I change the security settings of Google App's Exchange protocol?

Tags: google-workspace, security

I'm using Google Apps's Exchange protocol. When I use it on my iPhone, I notice that it sets the phone to automatically lock after a minute and this value cannot be changed. I'm wondering if there is any way to tweak this value in Google Apps.

**Update:** I'm using the Standard Edition of Google Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweaking the security settings is a feature of the Premier edition, as described in [this support article](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173393).

Edit: [From this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=01ae1e93566db98a&hl=en&start=80), it appears Google has changed this. If you delete your Exchange account, then disable and re-enable the mobile sync service in Google Apps, it appears that this reverts the policy to not require an automatic lock.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I believe Google has fixed it, so there is no more security requirement. You have to pay for a premier account to change the settings. Also, be sure to install the hotfix from apple. If you remove your mail account from your iphone and re-add it, you should be all set.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3398

Comment: This didn't require for me to download any hotfix. I just had to remove and add the account, I believe.